# Current day display on day later

Tags: datetime

in the CP settings, timezone is set to UTC +1 Europe/Zurich
when I try this code:

```
{% set currDay = now|date() %}
    {{ currDay|date('l d F Y') }}
```

it outputs "Mercredi, 16 janvier 2019", but we're still Tuesday 15th

Craft 3.0.37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{% set currDay = now|date('M j, Y H:i:s') %}
{{ currDay }}
```

Applying the `|date()` filter to the `now` object when you set the variable `currDay` makes `currDay` a string. When you then try try to reapply `|date()` a second time, something funny must be happening..?